# Calling Ansible hostvars group variable at later point in play

Tags: ansible

During my playbook I create a variable for one set of machines the apps. Namely a password for a user db_password. It is within the group apps only at this point.

I am trying to recall that variable during a later part of the play for a different set of hosts that belong to a different group using hostvars. I have tried a number of things and it doesn't seem to work. Below is the main playbook as well as the main.yml for the 2 roles called.

My problem is it will not show the variable for the db_password when I try and debug it on the db servers. I think I am on the right track with the hostvars concept but open to new ideas. I know I could also write the output of the set_fact db_password to a file and then move it to the db server and have it be read from that but I am trying to keep this within this one playbook. Any thoughts and help is appreciated

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true

- hosts: apps
  roles:
- { role: test_app}

- hosts: db
  roles:
- { role: test_db }
```

main.yml for test_app

```
- name: "Setup TPMS {{ app_server_hostname }} | GENERATE password"
 set_fact: db_password={{lookup('password', '/dev/null 
 chars=ascii_letters,digits,hexdigits length=10')}}

 - name: user create
   user:
   name: testing
   update_password: always
   password: "{{ db_password}}"
   state: present
```

main.yml for test_db

```
- name: show var
  debug: "{{ hostvars[groups['apps'][0]]['db_password'] }}"
```

current error I am seeing I am expecting the password to return not hello world

```
 TASK [test_db : show var] 
 ok: [server104] => {
 "msg": "Hello world!"
```

Comment: What error do you get from that debug?  BTW is that debug valid?  Shouldn'it be `debug: msg=...`?

Comment: Added into my question the current error I am seeing as adding comments didn't give the error in a clean way

Comment: Right, and that output brings me to the second part of my comment.  The debug module needs a `msg` or `var` argument.  So `- debug: msg='foo'`

Comment: thanks for fixing that part of it, now that I am actually getting some return that I was expecting, ie the password for just one machine how would I get a line by line for each pair of app and db servers. 

Right now it "{{ hostvars[groups['apps'][0]]['db_password'] }}"

returns only one password for both database machins. Instead of the 0 would I put a variable in the 0's place indicating the hostname of my app servers?

Comment: Well which server do you want?  Just use `hostvars['appserver1.name']` perhaps?   Kinda depends on what the context of  how you need to use it.

Comment: I'm not worried about the indentation I edited it weirdly to get it to display in this posting correctly. 

As far as the naming and context goes. I want the set_fact db password that is generated on password app101 to be the same password  used on db101 if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is wrong. Correct indentation is below

```
- hosts: apps
  roles:
    - { role: test_app}
- hosts: db
  roles:
    - { role: test_db }
```

.

```
- name: "Setup TPMS {{ app_server_hostname }} | GENERATE password"
  set_fact:
    db_password: ...
    chars: ...
```

.

```
- name: user create
  user:
    name: testing
    update_password: always
    password: "{{ db_password}}"
    state: present
```